# how to implement java.lang.Classloader getResources()?

Tags: java, classloader

I have searched quite a lot, but didnt find any satisfactory answer. so please forgive me if this is too obvious to you.

I have written a classloader which is getting a callback for getResources(), and the resource is a folder name. In the classloader i have the root path from which the resource is being asked for.

now the `getResources()` requires me to return an `'Enumeration'` of URL.

I am not getting any idea how to create an `Enumeration`, how to implement its `hasMoreElements()` and `nextElement()` inside `getResources()`. I am not able to see the connection between the two.

Cant i simple search for the subpath from the root and return the absolute path of the resource as a URL? why need to create this complicated `Enumeration`?

Thanks,
VImal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually, the two most important methods, that you have to override in your own classloader, are `public Class findClass(String name)` and `public InputStream getResourceAsStream(String name)`. Others can be delegated to the parent classloader in most cases. That means that you must have a very special purpose in overriding `getResources()`. What is it?

In either case you can easily add put a logger inside, delegate method to parent classloader and see what is requested and returned by parent classloader.

**UPDATE**

If, as per your comment, you want to *load classes/resources from a path which is generated at runtime*, you should do the following:
when path is passed to classloader (say `/home/user1/`), it should recursively list it's content storing files in two different collections - class files and other files. The first collection will be used for classloading, the second - for resources.

For each file in resource collection you define it's resource path according to http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/ClassLoader.html#getResource%28java.lang.String%29 and get the URL from file: `URL url = file.toURI().toURL();` 
These path and URL you store as key->value somewhere in a map and use it in method in question.

As for resource path, I believe it should be somewhat relative to the path, which was passed to your classloader: `/home/user1/img/logo.gif` => `/img/logo.gif`

Comment: hi, i have to write a classloader to load classes/resources from a path which is generated at runtime. so it is not available in original classpath when the VM starts. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

`Enumeration` is a very old Java class that's been superceded by the newer Collections library. You can get one by creating a `Collection` (of a single element) and then calling `Collections.enumeration()` on it:

```
Enumeration<String> enumInstance = Collections.enumeration(Arrays.asList("Bla"));
```